# Laravel PHP Process cannot run node

Tags: php, node.js, angular, laravel, npm

I am trying to build an angular project from a Laravel project.

When I run an exec command from Laravel I got `env: node: No such file or directory`

Steps to reproduce :

1. create Laravel project: `laravel new laravel-bug`
2. create angular project: `ng new angular-bug`

In the Laravel file routes/web.php, in the / route, add:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
$process = new Process('cd /path/to/angular-bug && ng build');
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
});
```

This will output the result, which for me is env: node: No such file or directory

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue before when `node` wasn't in the path of the web server user. The second argument to the `Process::run()` method is an array of environment variables. Use it to set a path.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
$env = ["PATH" => "/sbin;/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/path/to/node/if/its/different"];
$process = new Process('cd /path/to/angular-bug && ng build');
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
    }
}, $env);
```

The problem is that somewhere in this build process something is just calling `node` and expecting it will be in the path. (I think I experienced it when running `npm`.) This is not a great thing to do, and the software should be aware of where it’s located due to a compile-time setting or information from the package management system, or it should attempt to locate it.

Comment: Oh my... @miken32 this is working ^^ How can I know what is the correct path to add ? For now I added the entire world: `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Depends where `node` is. `command -v node` will tell you that. But nothing wrong with what you have there.

Comment: I just updated my answer to explain a bit more what’s going on.